# Change BackgroundImage of form from Custom Control running in Panel

Tags: c#, image, winforms, background, controls

My project consists of a form with a panel that contains a custom control.
In this custom control I have buttons that change the background image.

My issue is; these buttons only change the background image of the custom control that they are placed in, and I need them to change the background image of the main form containing the panel with the custom control.

My current code:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BackgroundSkinsPath));
```

I need something that will in effect accomplish this:

```
MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BackgroundSkinsPath));
```

ie: Change background image of `MainForm.cs` from `CustomControl.cs`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent

Comment: I'm not really sure how to adapt any of the answers from that question to my particular circumstances

Comment: Sorry I was thinking that this was a WPF app. Is it a WinForms project?

Comment: Yes, it is a WinForm. Sorry, should have specified that.

Comment: Ok, then we could look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820606/get-access-to-parent-control-from-user-control-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something different:

```
Form MainForm = Application.OpenForms["(The name of the form in which I wanted to change the background)"];

//...

MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BackgroundSkinsPath));
```

It ended up being a lot simpler than I thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Control.FindForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that, like this

```
this.FindForm().BackgroundImage = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the control's parents and change the `BackgroundImage`:

```
if(this.Parent!=null && this.Parent.Parent!=null)
   this.Parent.parent.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BackgroundSkinsPath));
```