# User-selectable BackgroundImage from settings file (Physical and Resource)

Tags: c#, string, image, background, resources

I've got a WinForms app with a radio button that changes the background image of my form, and saves the location of that background image to a text file, so the background that the user selected gets loaded each time they run the application.

Right now, those background images need to be located in the user's `/(USERNAME)/My Documents/Application Name/Skins/Default/` folder.

What I would like the application to do is as follows:

The user can select a "Custom" skin, located in the `/(USERNAME)/My Documents/Application Name/Skins/Custom/` folder.

And also be able to select from the "Default" skins, but have those skins located in the project's resources. My problem here is: I can read and write the physical location of the custom skin from the settings file, but I'm not sure how to add the ability to choose a background from a built-in project resource location with this method, and still have it save to the settings file.

Here is the code I'm using for physical locations right now:

```
    private void DefaultThemeButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");
        string currentBackgroundImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application", "Skins", "Default", "DefaultBackground.png");
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (currentBackgroundImage);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadLines(SettingsPath).Skip(7).Take(1).First()); ;
```

I would like to be able to accomplish something like this:

```
// USER SELECTS DEFAULT BACKGROUND
    private void DefaultThemeButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");
        string currentBackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.DefaultBackground))  // THIS IS THE PART I'M STUCK ON
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (currentBackgroundImage);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadLines(SettingsPath).Skip(7).Take(1).First()); ;

// USER SELECTS CUSTOM BACKGROUND

    private void CustomThemeButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");
        string currentBackgroundImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application", "Skins", "Custom", "Background.png");
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (currentBackgroundImage);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.File.ReadLines(SettingsPath).Skip(7).Take(1).First()); ;
```

Is there a way to read the resource location like a physical location without having to actually have the file in a physical folder?

Comment: just a question ... why not let the client browse for the file and then make a copy of it in your applications folder? that way you can check for the file and set it as background every time..

Comment: That's pretty much what it's already doing, but what I'm hoping to be able to do, is have the "Default" theme of my application be based in the project resources, and have the "Custom" themes based in physical folders. That way the user can edit the custom themes all they want, but still be able to go back to the default themes if they want to/screw something up; because they won't have access to alter the default themes

Comment: so assuming you already know how to add the files to the resources but you dont know how to read from the resources?or did i not get it again? :p

Comment: My "Default" theme will already be built into the project resources, I need a way to for my application to convert that resource name/location(or whatever you want to call it) to a string, and write that string to my settings file, so that the location can be called each time the app is loaded. I already have the ability to do that with images in a physical folder in the user's "My Documents" folder, I just don't know how to save the location of a built-in resource to a text file. I hope that helps explain my issue.

Comment: i dont understand why you want to save the location of the resource into a text file but to access it all you need to do is to cast and then reach it from the properties.resources....with being able to access it u can just apply it whenever the user wants to switch back to the default,imho using the text file is a mistake to begin with but thats your decision.if accessing is the issue i can write a sample on how to access it through resources.i hope that can help

Comment: I know how to access it to apply it with a button/etc, but I'm not sure how to make it so that if the user selects the default skin, they can exit the application and it will get loaded automatically every time they open the application until they select a different one.

Comment: Actually, I have another idea. I'll try just saving a simple string to my settings file containing the user's selection (ie. "default" or "custom" instead of the full path), then just have my application handle the locations programatically with `IF` statements that check the string that was saved to the settings file. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: well its not that complicated...all you need is a binary 0-1 variable in your text file.if your application has SQL database  you can just create a table and go further with your application-settings..that way your application can load its settings from the database real-time.else you could just save a number in the file,or use the registry to store the data...i.e if value was 0 set the background from the resources,else set the background from the x path,while x is the external path that you copy the user selected file to.i hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I think I'll try to do. I don't know how to use databases yet, so I'll still with just a `Settings.cfg` file. My application only has a few settings to store in there anyway, and I can just store them as simple strings for the most part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99636/discussion-between-virgil-and-patrick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to my problem by changing how my backgrounds are selected. On my theme selection form, the user's selected theme gets written to my `Settings.cfg` file as a simple string consisting of the name of the theme.

The theme then gets loaded from either the resources, or the physical location of the theme, depending on which one was selected.

Theme selection form:

```
    private void DEFAULTTHEME_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");            
        string SelectedTheme = "Default Theme"; //THIS GETS WRITTEN TO THE SETTINGS FILE           
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (SelectedTheme);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.DefaultBackground;
    }

    private void LIGHTTHEME_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");            
        string SelectedTheme = "Light Theme"; //THIS GETS WRITTEN TO THE SETTINGS FILE           
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (SelectedTheme);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.LightBackground;
    }

    private void CUSTOMTHEME_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");
        string CustomBackground = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Skins", "Custom", "Background.png"); //THIS IS SO MY APPLICATION KNOWS THE LOCATION OF THE CUSTOM BACKGROUND IMAGE
        string SelectedTheme = "Custom Theme"; //THIS GETS WRITTEN TO THE SETTINGS FILE
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsPath);
        lines[7] = (SelectedTheme);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SettingsPath, lines);
        MainForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(CustomBackground);
    }
```

When my main form loads, it checks the contents of the settings file at line 8, and converts that to a string (the name of the selected theme). The form then decides which background image to display, depending on the contents of the string:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
 string SettingsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Settings.cfg");
 string CustomBackground = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Application Name", "Skins", "Custom", "Background.png");
 string SelectedTheme = System.IO.File.ReadLines(SettingsPath).Skip(7).Take(1).First();

//LOAD THEME
        if (SelectedTheme.Equals("Default Theme"))
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.DefaultBackground;
        }
        else if (SelectedTheme.Equals("Light Theme"))
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.LightBackground;
        }
        else if (SelectedTheme.Equals("Custom Theme"))
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(CustomBackground);
        else
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.DefaultBackground;
        }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do this, since I'm very new to C#, but this method works extremely well for my application.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Control.BackgroundImage = Project.Properties.Resources.resourceName;
```

or

```
this.Control.BackgroundImage =   ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Resource.Image")));
```

so with this you wont really need to save the path of it anywhere as you already have it within the resources..thats why i think saving the path is not needed...all you need to do is to somehow tell your application to load one of the either resource or external file through the text file.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to set a controls BackgroundImage from a resource, my question was regarding converting that resource to a string, but I've got it figured out now.